# call function A in function A after success call function B in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, async-await, angular-http

> I am using some functions that send $http async request to server side.i want to call same current function after relogin user if response is "notlogin". I think i need to  use promise but how?

```
 $scope.A = function(){
    $http({..,async: "isAsync",...})
    .success(function (response) {
        if (response.d == "notlogin") {
            if ($scope.B())//call back login to refresh session
                $scope.A();//repeat request if login return true
        }
    });
};

 $scope.B= function () {

        $scope.userlogin_error = "wait...";
        $http({...,async: "isAsync",...}).success(function (response) {

            if (response.d == "True") {
                $scope.userlogin_error = "login success";
                $scope.user_islogin = true;

                return true;
            }
});
}
```

Comment: What is function `B`?

Comment: it is login function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try make $scope.B() as [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) (It's something asynchronous, I understand correctly?);

```
$scope.B = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    if(something) {
        defer.resolve(data);
    } else {
        defer.reject(error);
    }
    return defer.promise;
};

$scope.B().then(function(data){
    $scope.A();
});
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern if `scope.B` already is using `$http` and can simply return that promise

Comment: i am new in angular ... can you please make answer clear?i edited question.

Comment: i tested this but .then() didn't fire .i used $scope.$apply(function() {
  deffer.resolve(thing);
});  but not worked

Comment: Thanks  @user3335966 i added settimeout to your solution and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can return success callback of $scope.B() by just returning the $http call

```
$scope.A = function(){
   $http({..,async: "isAsync",...}).success(function (response) {
    if (response.d == "notlogin") {
        $scope.B().success(function(data){
           if(data.d == "True"){
                $scope.userlogin_error = "login success";
                $scope.user_islogin = true;
                $scope.A();
           }
        });
    }
   });
};

 $scope.B= function () {
   return $http({...,async: "isAsync",...});
 };
```

Comment: in my code i return boolean instead of $http and because of async call, the condition for call function A not working. it seems no difference between bool or $http return.